# Getting Invalid binding path while binding to UI

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a view model in which I have a class called FormItem. There is a form item  property in this class which controls the visibility of a property in form item class 
This property is of type Visibility Provider which is another class. I have given below the class definations.

```
public class FormItem : FormSchema, IDictionary<string, object>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VisibilityStateProvider VisibilityProvider { get; set; }

    public FormItem()
    {
        VisibilityProvider = new VisibilityStateProvider(this);
    }
}


public class VisibilityStateProvider : IPropertyStateProvider
{
    private FormItem FormItem;

    public VisibilityStateProvider(FormItem formItem)
    {
        FormItem = formItem;
    }


    public bool this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetVisibilityValue(key);
        }
    }

    private bool GetVisibilityValue(string key)
    {
        bool result=true;
        try
        {
            returns true or false on basis of some computation
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void NotifyVisibilityChanged(string key)
    {
        var a= $"Item[{key}]";

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(a));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Now when we are trying to Bind the Visibility Provider in UWP using following code:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.FormItem.VisibiltyProvider[key],Convertor = {StaticResource BoolToVisibilityOCnvertor}}"/>
```

We are getting invalid binding path. Now if we are directly binding to the property we are getting property change as null. I have already asked question on StackOverflow in the following question:
[Binding through IDictionary<string,object> property changed event handler is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997601/binding-through-idictionarystring-object-property-changed-event-handler-is-nul?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it looks like what is needed is to have an observable Dictionary, something like -

```
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

As far as the binding goes, if you know the key value, you can directly use that in the binding rather than "key". For example, in your case if the TextBlock has to displayed based on the dictionary: {"ShowTextBlock" : true}, then you can bind like this -

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Dictionary[ShowTextBlock], Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}" />
```

Comment: In this case i am getting property change even handler as null.

Comment: Please check the link to my previous question on stackoverflow for reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997601/binding-through-idictionarystring-object-property-changed-event-handler-is-nul?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I am not sure about this piece of code: var a= $"Item[{key}]"; Specifically, where is the "Item"? I would call the Propertychanged simply using the propertyname.